# How can I make my wordpress theme installable?

Tags: installation, wordpress-theming

I have made a basic wordpress theme and I want to be installable to other blogs. Lets suppose we have this theme:

```
wp-content
|
|- myTheme
|--- <theme files>
```

How I will export the theme and make it installable to another blogs (if possible via wp-cli too)?

## Edit1

The basic philosophy is to have a complete theme with translations etc etc into a zip file (including translations) where in order to upload from the dashboard in order to be able to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "installable"? The installation of a theme is pretty much copying it into the themes folder. If you want to make it searchable, add it to the repository.

Comment: able to install into other wordpress sites.

Comment: Then you are ready to go. Every theme is always able to be installed to other wordpress sites. And there is bug in your scheme: The folder is \wp-content\themes\<yourthemename>\*

Comment: but what happens if I need to vendor-share and some translations too?

Comment: Just include whatever you want into your theme folder. I have no idea what you mean by "vendor-share", just zip your theme folder. That is all.